# iFrame embeded videos on WordPress and SEO

Tags: iframe, video, seo, embed

I'm starting my own website that is focused on a specific niche set of videos that I've been posting on wordpress. These videos are hosted on google drive or other sites that give me iFrame codes so I can embed them on my site.

From my research, I've read that using iFrames aren't such a good idea for SEO and some of my research has led me to believe that I should be using a subdomain for the actual video content itself. So essentially, what I may do is post on Wordpress with the title of my video and put some text content on that post about the general info of the video, and then have a "watch now" button on their that links to the subdomain with just that video on it.

My question is, will using a subdomain for my videos be the most ideal situation for SEO? I cannot host these videos on my site so I would either have to do this or just have a over 200 iframe embeded videos on my site all with their own page.

Any advice is appreciated! thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't ask questions about SEO?

Comment: Okay, just realized that I cannot. You could've at least explained that john and not come off as rude and downvote my question, and I've seen that you pretty much do that on all the SEO questions. whats your issue?

Comment: Why are you asking off topic questions?  Isn't that rude?

Comment: I simply made an error and did not know I could not. John and Will, you really do sure know how to make a new member feel welcomed on this site. Yes, I made an error, and I fully admit that, but the way you guys are handling this is ridiculous. I hope you guys feel better about yourselves at the end of the day with your feeling of "internet superiority" . I will not be returning to this site, peace.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en read this article. I suggest you should maintain your won server. If you are using iframe  tag then please explain your video like article description .... 
Thanks